# Automatic java classes to work with mySQL

Tags: java, jdbc

When developing for Microsoft Visual Studio and MS SQL Server, I would create stored procedures in MS SQL Server and a dataset in VS. The dataset is created with a wizard that effectively creates classes that my C# code can use to execute stored procedures and read data from the database. What is nice about this is that the classes abstract the interface with the database and provide an object oriented way of dealing with the database. The creation of classes from datasets guarantees strongly typed fields that are bound to actual database columns, which is really good. The real beauty with datasets is that if you change the database and refresh your dataset, it automatically rebuilds the classes. This prevents you from having a wrong data type in a class if you were to manually create those classes.

Is there something equivalent in Java / Eclispe development when working with a mySQL database? JDBC isn't an object oriented approach, so I'm wondering what alternative there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to communicate with a database in Java is probably to use an ORM framework such as [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), possibly together with [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html). Hibernate abstracts database tables to Java classes, and uses JDBC under the hood.

> Is there something equivalent in Java / Eclispe development when working with a mySQL database? JDBC isn't an object oriented approach, so I'm wondering what alternative there is.

Hibernate has a **reverse engineering** feature ([Hibernate Tools](http://hibernate.org/tools/)). It allows you to automatically create Java classes from your database. Alternatively, you can let Hibernate create the database tables for you, which is specified by this parameter `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) would probably be a good starting point.